# How to return two functions with factory?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying return two functions with factory but I can't do this.

How could I do this ?

trying

```
app.factory('HeaderFactory', function(Base64){
    var email = 'admin@admin.com.br';
    var senha = 'password'

    return {
        getHeader: {
            headerJSON: function(){
                return {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(email + ':' + senha),
                    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' 
                }
            }

            headerNotJSON: function(){
                return {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(email + ':' + senha),
                    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                }
            }
        }           

    };
});
```

**Use**

```
HeaderFactory.getHeader.headerJSON();
HeaderFactory.getHeader.headerNotJSON();
```

Comment: There should be a comma after the last `headerJSON` curly brace, and before the word `headerNotJSON`

Comment: wow...you all right, thanks a lot !